# open shared folder to specific user

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

Let's say that I have [created a share folder to specific user](http://www.windows10compatible.com/blog/how-to-share-a-folder-in-windows-10/) I want to test it and don't know how.

I mean I know I can right click on the folder and view the properties, but I want to "test it on live".

I tried `window+R` to open "Run" and then entered `\\10.1.1.10` and it showed me the shared folder but I can't open it.

[image]

[image]

> my question: how to open it with the user that specific user that binded to this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to windows with the new user that you created, and then check if you have access to the folder via [UNC](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230)